# Set a picture in “return” in js condition or assign a style with “content”

Tags: javascript, css, return, conditional-statements

Now I have that condition:

```
    function getArrow(num) {

    if(num > 0) return "↑";
    if(num === 0) return "-";
    else return "↓";
}
```

But I need a pictures instead of arrows so I understand that I can pull up the style with the picture, but how to implement it?

Comment: `if(num > 0) return "<img src='arrow_up.jpg' alt='↑' />";`?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is creating the styles and the function `getArrow()` returns the last part of the style name.

*This way, you can put images into the style blocks.*

```js
function getArrow(num) {
  if (num > 0) return "up";
  if (num === 0) return "none";
  else return "down";
}

document.querySelector('span').classList.add('ui-arrow-' + getArrow(5));
```

```css
.ui-arrow-up::after {
  content: '\2191'
}

.ui-arrow-down::after {
  content: '\2193'
}

.ui-arrow-none::after {
  content: '\203e'
}
```

```html
<span>EleFromStack</span>
```

*Use symbol codes instead of symbos because come editors / browsers may not recocnize them.

Comment: But for some reason it returned me the word 'up' instead arrow